# How to respond to questions about my own progress in my PhD

Tags: phd

I'm a PhD student and sometimes it happens that my advisor will ask me how I think my PhD is going. I'm not sure how to come up with a good objective answer to this question. Mostly because I don't know if things are going to slow or fast etc.

How can I provide a good answer to this question? I guess I can point out if things are going as planned, but this doesn't really answer the question.

Comment: Perhaps the actual question is "how do you feel about how things are going?"  That's different from the more objective question of how close you actually are to finishing and helps in understanding your motivation and persistence.

Comment: That seems to be a weird question. My advisor only ask me the progress. Then he tells me whether or not it is going well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used to answer to such questions by describing the current concrete state of my research:

- recently accepted/submitted papers
- papers being prepared/written
- upcoming plans

I then left it up to the asker whether that is enough information or whether they want to make any more specific enquiries.